# Отличие инициализации атрибута в методе __init__ и вне его

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы, list

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, когда я пишу:

```
class CustomerList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
    def add_customer(self, customer):
        self.names.append(customer)
        print(self.names)
a, b = CustomerList(), CustomerList()
a.add_customer('Ben')
b.add_customer('Joe')
```

выводятся списки `['Ben']`, `['Joe']`.

А если написать без `__init__`:

```
class CustomerList():
    names = []
    def add_customer(self, customer):
        self.names.append(customer)
        print(self.names)
a, b = CustomerList(), CustomerList()
a.add_customer('Ben')
b.add_customer('Joe')
```

то выведутся списки `['Ben']`, `['Ben', 'Joe']`? В чем суть метода `__init__`? Почему в первом случае при добавлении `'Joe'` он понимает, что объект `b` - новый объект и для него заново создается пустой список, в который мы потом добавляем `'Joe'`, а во втором случае при добавлении `'Joe'` он считает, что уже до этого был добавлен `'Ben'`? Как именно на все это влияет `__init__`? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во втором случае:

```py
class CustomerList():
    names = []

    def add_customer(self, customer):
        self.names.append(customer)
        print(self.names)

a, b = CustomerList(), CustomerList()
a.add_customer('Ben')
b.add_customer('Joe')
```

Создаётся `names` как **переменная класса**, то есть, общая для всех объектов класса. В итоге, при добавлении значений в список этой переменной, они добавляются сразу для всех. А в методе `__init__` мы создаём **переменную экземпляра**, отдельную новую переменную для *каждого* нового объекта, что позволяет хранить в них разные значения, и что вероятно будет правильным в данном случае.

При этом, в случае с переменной класса, мы можем обращаться к самому классу, например: `print(CustomerList.names)`. Более того, когда в коде экземпляра класса происходит обращение `self.names` и переменная не обнаруживается среди переменных экземпляра, она ищется как раз среди переменных класса (а также среди классов-родителей). Это работает через особую встроенную переменную `__dict__`, которая есть и у объектов-экземпляров, и у классов (которые тоже являются объектами), и она рекурсивно просматривается при обращении через точку.

Почитать по теме:

- [medium.com: Class vs Instance Variables](https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd)
- [www.digitalocean.com: Understanding Class and Instance Variables in Python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)
- [Переменные класса и экземпляра в Питоне на русском](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)
- [habr.com: Пользовательские атрибуты в Python, переменная `__dict__`](https://habr.com/ru/post/137415/)

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор **init**  определяет атрибуты для каждого создаваемого экземпляра класса. Поэтому, в первом случае  каждый экземпляр получает свой список.

Во втором случае атрибут names общий для всех объектов класса, поэтому каждый экземпляр, обращаясь этому списку, изменяет его.

Я думаю будет уместно добавить ещё про пространство имён. Во втором случае у каждого экземпляра нет в namespace списка names (т.к. он не был создан при инициализации), поэтому идёт обращение к namespace класса, откуда и берётся список names.